# Relocate one line to find the equality

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

[image]

just Relocate one of the line to find the equality. Tricky!

Note: No Inequality sign is accepted!

Comment: Please tag this [tag:roman-numerals], for some reason it's not letting me

Comment: @smci: The system isn’t letting you tag this question as [roman-numerals] because that tag doesn’t exist, and you don’t have the privilege to create new tags.  Why do you think that it’s so important that people be able to see that this question involves Roman numerals without opening it? Before you waste any more effort suggesting unwelcome changes, you might want to try to get a better feel for what sort of changes will be approved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My thoughts:

> **$\dfrac{X/II}{V}=I$**

Answer (score 11):

I dont really understand what's allowed or not but maybe

> ((X / 1) / V )  = 2 
>  So basicly split the X in the middle so it becomes a divider and "I" that is moved to the right side of the equality sign

Comment: This answer could be improved by expressing it (1) entirely as Roman numerals and (2) with the same multi-line geometric layout used in the question, as [JonMark Perry’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/51757/19765#51759) did. On the other hand, you did (unlike JonMark Perry) *explain* your answer. Also, you answered first. Also, this is the answer I thought of when I saw the question, so +1 from me. And, aside from my first two bullet points, I don’t know why this answer isn’t accepted.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say, take the bar from the 2nd X and put it on the right of the equality :

```
X / I 
----- = II
  V
```

(10 / 1) / 5 = 2.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! Note that another, earlier, [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51758/11110) already mentions this; generally, duplicate answers will be deleted.

Comment: @Glorfindel I think it's not duplicate. Though the lines moved are same, the equations are different.

Comment: @Techidiot: No, this answer ***is*** identical to [user3660570’s answer](/q/51757/19765#51758), aside from trivial formatting differences.

Answer (score 4):

How about if I do the following?

> [image]

Comment: Nope, that requires two line changes (leftmost 'X' -> 'V') plus two spacing changes on the numerator, also making the middle 'x' smaller, and 'x' as multiplication sign is not very Roman (then again neither is '/' for division)

Answer (score 2):

I think this fits.

> Intrepret like this: [image]

Comment: Well, picture ought to deserve a Nobel prize for its impeccable BUT, isn't it ?